# How to use value from bash script when creating resource via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

This is a generic workflow terraform question (I am a terraform beginner).

I need to create a new aws resource via terraform. The structure I have is

```
resource "some_aws_resource" "resource_name" {
   name = var.resource_name
   role_name = var.role_name

   another_key = another_value
}
```

The value `another_value` is derived from vars entered by the user through a bash script
`find_another_value.sh` for example

```
resource "null_resource" "find_another_value" {
   provisioner "local-exec" {
      command     = "shell_scripts/find_another_value.sh"
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash"]
    working_dir = path.module

    environment = {
      DAR = var.aws_dar
      RAD = var.aws_rad
    }
   }

}
```

should return  `another_value`

How do I pass the output `another_value` of the `null_resource` to the first resource and make sure that the non null resource waits until the `null_resource` returns the value?

The `find_another_value.sh` script will use the input variables to query aws via the aws cli to find the value it needs to return.

If there is a better/easier way that would also be good to know.

Comment: Why not use terraform variables instead of a shell script?

Comment: You can't do this. `null_resource` is not for returning anything to TF. I think you have to re-thing your design as Marko suggested.

Comment: @MarkoE  I have to execute complicated logic in find_another_value.sh: retrieve some values using the aws cli.

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve, i.e., which values?

Comment: @MarkoE In one use case it is the organizational unit where I want to place a new account

Answer (score 1):

For waiting you will use  depends_on = []

```
resource "some_aws_resource" "resource_name" {
   depends_on =[null_resource.find_another_value]
   name = var.resource_name
   role_name = var.role_name
   another_key = another_value.value
}
```

To extract value from a resource
We will write a resource out
We will add value
Edit the resource then the name and then the line we want its value

```
output "another_value" {

  description = "another_value from null resource find_another_value ."

  value = null_resource.find_another_value.provisioner "local-exec"
}
```

Comment: The syntax is not correct for this line:

value = null_resource.find_another_value.provisioner "local-exec"

"local-exec" is not expected there